# USB-C Battery pack - charging and powering other devices using the same USB-C plug

Tags: usb-c

I'm designing an ultra-small LiPo 1C battery pack using the TopPower TP5400 charging control and boost output regulator IC. Design is working fine, but currently I'm using a microUSB socket for charging and a USB-C plug to plug the battery pack into the device to be powered.

But I want to use the USB-C plug for powering a device, as well as plugging it into a charger's USB-C socket to recharge. There are two design issues:

1. My USB-C plug is always powering 5V at the VBUS pins - this is wrong due to the spec (unless it is sufficient to advertise it being a DFP by the included 56kΩ pull-up) - and
2. I have to sense if the battery pack is plugged into the charger or into the device it is supposed to power.

Any hint for a clever (and small) design to switch power and sense the CC pins?

Comment: Small circuit? Typically a dedicated usb c dual role power controller IC and a handful of mosfets.

Comment: Are you sure your USB-C plug doesn't have a resistor inside to activate Vbus?